# Passing Arrays from MS Flow to WCF service

Tags: c#, forms, wcf, https, wcf-data-services

I am making a MS Flow. On the submission of a MS Form I have to trigger `HTTP POST` request and send form field values to WCF service method. I am able to achieve this with the fields that are **string** but stuck with MultiSelect dropdown. For Multiselect, `HTTPS POST` Method is passing parameters in **array** format something like `[\"A\",\"B\"]`. I have tried to capture these parameters something like this in WCF .

```
public string InsertIntoMyTable(string[] MyParam)
{ }
```

But this seems not working out. Is **string[]** is wrong datatype? then which datatype should we use to get this array to my WCF method?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with `string[]` in WCF. in order to help you, i need more information. I'm just going to list the common mistake in WCF and hope one of the could help you:
at first make sure you didn't mark the request body wrapped. something like this: `BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`
then make sure you send the valid request. this isn't `[\"A\",\"B\"]` valid JSON array.

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:

    [\"A\",\"B\"]
    -^
    Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', ']', got 'undefined'

validated by jsonlint
```

at list try to enable the WCF help page. its very useful in this kind of situations.